# don't get the other tabs on my paypal profile

Tags: paypal, hyperlink

I'm developping a website where I'll be putting some paypal subscription buttons.
I haven't ever been doing this before. So I'googled a lot and found many tutorials on how payments work with paypal.

But now my problem is, while following one of the tutorial, I have to create a subscribtion button but the link on which I'm supposed to click doesn't appear in my profil. I've checked other tutorials, to find if there is another way to create this subscribe button in vain.
And I also noticed that I'm only having two tab links the 'MyAcount' tab and the 'Send Payment' tab.

Now I created this paypal account only to make some testes. So I did not link any card, there no activity ... nothing special. And I wonder if this isn't the reason why my acount look limited. 
Did I have to upgrade or to enter my card number to be fully using paypal?

Answer (score 0):

This could have either something to do with the type of an account you have, or be caused by the country that your account is set up in.  Not all countries can receive payments.  I would have to look at the account that you are using.  However if your account should have this option but for some reason you are not seeing it, you could also try creating a button [here](http://paypal.github.io/JavaScriptButtons/).